# Adding module name to application.config.php file in Zend Skeleton

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am newbie to zend framework and i am trying to configure the zend..

In that process i created some album module.. by following the [Zend user-guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/user-guide/modules.html)

1)  I have configured **virtual host**... as

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName zend.localhost
   DocumentRoot /var/www/Zend_project/public
   SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
  <Directory /var/www/Zend_project/public>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Everything works well when i typed the following Url

```
   http://zend.localhost/
```

I got the page as below

[image]

2) After getting this page i started to create new module **Album** as per **User-guide**

I followed every step in user-guide... and created files and folders according to user-guide..

3) Finally i added Album module in application.config.php file

```
 // This should be an array of module namespaces used in the application.
 'modules' => array(
    'Application',
    'Album', // added as new module
  ),
```

After adding the module Album to **application.config.php**

I tried to refresh page with the above successful URL

```
      http://zend.localhost/
```

I got the error messages as follows

```
  Warning: include(/var/www/Zend_project/module/Album/config/module.config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/Zend_project/module/Album/Module.php on line 28

  Warning: include(): Failed opening '/var/www/Zend_project/module/Album/config/module.config.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/Zend_project/module/Album/Module.php on line 28 

 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Config being merged must be an array, implement the Traversable interface, or be an instance of Zend\Config\Config. boolean given.' in /var/www/Zend_project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/Listener/ConfigListener.php:317 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/Zend_project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/Listener/ConfigListener.php(127): Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ConfigListener->addConfig('Album', false) #1 [internal function]: Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ConfigListener->onLoadModule(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) #2 /var/www/Zend_project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) #3 /var/www/Zend_project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('loadModule', Object( in /var/www/Zend_project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/Listener/ConfigListener.php on line 317
```

**FYI**

I am using ubuntu 3.10 operation system

Where i am doing wrong..?

Any help would greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

this error means is , zend cann't load Album\config\module.config.php 
your code has problem in Album\Module.php or Album\config\module.config.php 
if your code hasn't syntax error in Module.php and your code has

```
public function getConfig() {
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
}
```

on this file something wrong in module.config.php . 
please show Album\Module.php and Album\config\module.config.php

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using this skeleton for your project. 100% functioning.

http://www.zf-beginners-guide.com/archives.html

Answer (score 0):

May be it is permissions issue, just try to run the following command and see if it works:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/Zend_project
```

where the www-data is the user of the apache server, if it worked then apache don't have the right to read or write on the files/folders in the project you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

As "amin arab" said, it can't load the module config, but if somebody is working on Windows (that's my case), I had to go back one folder to make it load correctly, so I changed this:

```
public function getConfig() {
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
}
```

to

```
public function getConfig() {
    return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';
}
```

In Module.php